# Generate custom id

Tags: java, database, hibernate, crud

I need to generate custom id (which is primary key) based on 3 other columns from this table. Those 3 columns are hashed and as a result I get id as a primary key. Can I do something like this using Hibernate and @GenericGenerator or I have to set up all CRUD operations manually?

The main question is with add method, because as far as I know @GenericGenerator operates with data that is already stored in database and on add method database knows nothing about the row, which is about to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a custom generator could be a very good way to go for your problem. With a custom generator, you can very easily generate the IDs the way you want. There is a really nice article on that topic with an example of how to implement and how to use a custom generator with Hibernate: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers#5-custom-generator

Comment: how can I pass my columns values into that method, if i'm adding a new row, for example?

Comment: @Evillain, have you looked at the example? You get the object as the second parameter. Just read the values from the passed object.